# How to create Universal application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, compatibility

Is there a possibility to create a same application for both iphone and ipad.If  yes means please clearly explain all controls(uitabelview,uiimageview etc...) for iphone will work for ipad.

And also give me a link for related studies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to create a universal app - Xcode even has a project that does some of the initial set up for you.

However, I believe the recommended approach is to use different NIB files/resources for each of the two targets and to use the appropriate UIKit objects for each device, as whilst the iPad supports all of the standard UIKit objects, there are some that are only available on the iPad. (See the "[iPad-Specific Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html)" section within the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS for the full details.)

As such, you'll generally find that you use a shared set of model objects, but it's quite possibly easier to simply use different view controllers for each device depending on your required functionality.

I'd recommend reading the [Introducing Universal Applications for iPhone OS](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf) PDF, as a good first step, as it outlines some of the issues you'll need to deal with.

Comment: Thank You middaparka...The PDF document useful for me to start creating "Universal Application"...